# SharePoint permissions for members - edit the whole page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

How come that my members on a site can edit the whole page? I want the members to be able to participate but NOT edit all the webparts??

If I understand this right I have a group named "Members". The group has a "permission level" in *Members*, that level is "participate" - and that should not mean edit and delete webparts? This is so confusing..But I want them to be able to edit documents and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Members group to use Contribute instead of Edit (Contribute is similar to Edit, but without the Manage Lists permission).  Unfortunately, the Edit Items permission will allow users to edit pages (pages are considered a list item in SharePoint). To prevent users from editing site pages:

1. Go to your Pages/Site Pages library
2. Break inheritance on the library (go to the library permissions, and click the ribbon button to break inheritance)
3. Change the permission level for your members group to view only.

See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640(v=office.15).aspx) link for info on Contribute.

[This](http://paulliebrand.com/2014/02/20/sharepoint-2013-edit-vs-contribute-what-the-hell-happened/) link mentions the change in 2013, and explains a bit of it.

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18203.sharepoint-2013-break-document-library-permissions-inheritance.aspx) link provides some pictures for breaking inheritance on a library.  They're about 1/3 of the way down the page.

Comment: Thanks! But even if I do that a row in Contribute says "Edit objects- edit objects in lists documents in documentlibrary and adjust webbpartpages in dokumentlibrary". That seems to make the whole page editable, you can deleate and and webparts? Why is webarts editing connected to documents editing?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way around that.  See my edit for a workaround.